# Importing classes & utilities in the manifest // JNA

Tags: classpath, manifest, jna

I'm a CS student and am in way over my head for an end of the year project, for which I need to find the dimensions and locations of a separate window. I've found that I need to use JNA libraries and understand how to do that but I don't understand how to import the JNA libraries through the manifest. Here is my file structure so far (I'm working in netbeans):

- Project Folder

  - dist Folder
  - nbproject Folder
  - src Folder
  - Test Folder
  - Build.xml
  - Game.exe <-- This is the exe I run from the java file itself. I need to find this window's size and location for use later in the project
  - jna.jar <-- need to implement this as a classpath
  - Manifest.mf <-- I supposedly need to edit this.

The reason I show you this is to ensure that I've put the JNA Jar in the correct place.

Next, here is my manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Class-Path: C:\Users\justi_000\Google Drive\4. APCS\JZMinesweeper\jna.jar
```

So I need to edit the bit after the `java -cp` but I don't know what to put there, and in what order. The java tuts, etc aren't of much help.

Additionally, are these imports correct? They may be the problem and I have correctly imported everything, but I doubt that.

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;
```

Comment: The class path statement within the manifest file should not be an absolute path as that will completely prevent you from moving the program anywhere else. No, it should be a path relative to the User working directory, something you can obtain by calling `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` Note that the jna.jar file should not be within your application's jar file.

Comment: Your second import you should do `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*` and that may not work without `jna-platform.jar`.

Comment: You might consider putting all your jar files (jna and jna-platform) in a lib directory and then you can just add lib/* to your classpath.

Comment: Hovercraft - Yes, I recognize this fact. I am just using an absolute path here because I wondered if that would be the problem
Daniel - Ok,  but that still leaves the problem of importing it. Thanks for the tip. Am I doing the classpath import correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, turns out, that it was a stupidly easy solution that my general incompetence caused me to miss.

Turns out it is actually possible to directly import libraries in IDEs...probably why they all include a tool for it. Blind old me has only ever used them once before (the perils of being a student) but we're all set. Simple as right click libraries>add jar.

Figured i would stick this here for future reference.